# What is the origin of "smiddock"?

Tags: etymology, german, dialects, pennsylvanian-english

## Pennsylvanian English: *smiddock*

Put your middle finger behind your thumb and flick it against your arm — or better, someone else’s. I believe this is usually called a *thump* nowadays.

But when I was a kid, let’s say 60 years ago, my mother, who was raised in northeast Pennsylvania, called it a ***smiddock*** (however that might be spelled).

I have never found a reference to this word, using any conceivable spelling, since then. Can anyone shed light on its origin? It sounds vaguely German.

Answer (score 3):

The [English Dialect Dictionary](https://archive.org/stream/cu31924088038421#page/n569/mode/1up) gives *smittock* as a derivative of *smite, smit* in the sense "particle, speck, smut"—this *smit-* is also the stem of *smithereens*.

But *smit-* also has the sense, going back to Middle English, "stroke, blow"—compare the verb *smite*.

I conjecture that your *smiddock* is the latter sense of *smit-* with the diminutive suffix *-ock* (as in *hillock*, *bullock*)—a local use or family coinage passed on within your family.

In speech the intervocalic /t/ would easily become /d/.

Comment: I only ever heard it spoken and could not swear she said dd or tt. The explanation is perfect. It would be nice to know if it was a localism to NEP-